# The App throws NullPointerException, but can't find why

Tags: java, android

As far as I can tell, all the variables were checked by me with the debugger and neither of them is null.

My "getCurrentGameId" method from GameService.java:

```
public long getCurrentGameId() {
    if(mGame != null && mGame.mModel != null) {
        return mGame.mModel.getId();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
Process: com.soccertimer.android.debug, PID: 28143
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.soccertimer.android.services.GameService.getCurrentGameId(GameService.java:107)
        at com.soccertimer.android.ui.GameListFragment.onListItemClick(GameListFragment.java:82)
        at com.soccertimer.android.ui.GameListFragment$$ViewInjector$1.onItemClick(GameListFragment$$ViewInjector.java:20)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: does `getId` return a `Long` or `long`?

Comment: Long, and that's the problem!

Comment: `Long`, being an object, can take a value that cannot be autounboxed to `long`, that is `null`. Only you can decide what behavior you want to have in this case.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept that answer, so that the question doesn't remain on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

The exception thrown because of a conflict between the `getCurrentGameId()` method which return `long` and the `getId()` method which return `Long`.
So, when the `getId()` method return `null`, the`NullPointerException` is thrown.

Changing the `getCurrentGameId(`) to return `Long` did the trick.